# Updating an object inside a vector?

Tags: c++, coordinates

So I'm updating the "Missile" vector list.
However, when I try to change the coordinates: x and y, they won't change?
I don't understand why, especially not when everything else updates inside of it?

```
    private:
std::vector<Missile> missiles;


    void shoot(Spawner spawn)
    {
        // 50.0f/3, 200.0f/3
        Missile missile = Missile(x + 90.5f, y, image.shader);
        missiles.push_back(missile);
    }
void update(GLFWwindow* window, Spawner spawn)
    {
        input(window, spawn);

        updatePosition(x, y);

        for (int i = 0; i < missiles.size(); i++)
        {
            Missile index = missiles.at(i);

            index.update();
        }
    }


// Inside the missile class:

public:
    Missile(float x, float y, Shader shader)
        : Sprite(x, y, 50.0f/3, 200.0f/3, shader, "res/Textures/Missile.png", 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f)
    {

    }

    void update()
    {
        x = 100.0f;

        updatePosition(x, y);
        std::cout << "Y: " << y << std::endl;
    }

    void render()
    {
        image.draw();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
Missile index = missiles.at(i);
```

you are making a *copy* of the `Missile`, so the original inside the vector is not modified.

Instead, you could do:

```
Missile &index = missiles.at(i);
```

to take a *reference* to the `Missile` in the vector.

Or simply:

```
missiles.at(i).update();
```